# use cases for tf::MessageFilter::setTolerance

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As currently implemented, this method has the effect that canTransform is being invoked with the exact timestamp, *and* with a timestamp that is "duration" later. So, it's not a tolerance in the sense that anything *within* that range would be okay, but it ensures that the transform is valid for the *full* range.

In a situation where there is no tf post-dating, the effect of such a setting will be that the callback of the MessageFilter is **delayed** until sensor_time+tolerance_duration. This is obvious, because if the transform has any dynamic links, it can't be known prior to that time.

However, it does mean that sensor data will be processed later than it could otherwise have been.

I'm wondering what the rationale for such a function is? When is this necessary, and could it be solved without having to wait until duration expires?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217429/use-cases-for-tf::messagefilter::settolerance/) by [ingo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23822/ingo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The purpose of this call is to support sensor data which does not represent information from exactly one time.

The most common use case for this is the [laser scan message](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html). You'll note in it's definition there is a time increment between readings. The timestamp in the header is for the first ray, and every other measurement is offset in time from that first measurement by the `time_increment`. This level of time accuracy is important for lasers mounted on on moving platforms, such as a nodding laser. The transform for the first ray vs the last ray can be notably different. Because of this you need to be able look up the transform at every time in the range of the measurements.

With the default message_filter behavior you will get a callback when the first ray is available for transform, but since the message filter does not know about the inherent duration of the message's data it will give you the callback right away. And if you try to project the laser scan into a point cloud using the [high fidelity API](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_geometry#High_fidelity_projection) it will throw an exception most times since you don't have transform data for the whole scan. The solution is to tell the message filter to hold the data for the expected additional duration of the message data using the `setTolerance` [method](http://docs.ros.org/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1MessageFilter.html#a984a3c8a7b3c9aaf18758d7b08337d51).

For an example usage see [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_pipeline/Tutorials/IntroductionToWorkingWithLaserScannerData)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ingo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23822/ingo/) on 2015-09-10**:
Ah! Thanks a lot for the explanation, now I get it. That means that in reality there won't be any additional delay, because the time of stamp+duration will already have passed once the LaserScan arrives. In my case, I was running tests in simulation. I guess I'll have to fix the simulator then ;-)

**Comment by [ingo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23822/ingo/) on 2015-09-10**:
oh, btw, would you consider the following use of setTolerance to be valid?
https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/costmap_2d/plugins/obstacle_layer.cpp#L179
It sets a fixed tolerance of 50ms. That can't be appropriate?